# recover an audio file killed before it could be closed

Tags: audio, data-recovery, audio-recording

I need to recover an audio file that lost power before the recording could be properly closed.  With a USB drive in a digital mixer, recording audio output, **the mixer got powered off without stopping the `[file write]` process.**

The filesystem is FAT32, no visible file under Windows or Linux.

---

Planning my Granddad's funeral service, I noticed the church had a mixer with a USB slot and recording controls.  They didn't even know it was there and were surprised when I showed it to them.

Day of the service I brought a thumb drive, started the recording, and verified it was tracking.  Unfortunately afterward they shut down the mixer without first hitting `[stop]`.  Since they didn't know it records I understand it's a habit to just kill power--*but on SuperUser we all know what that does to data integrity*.
:,(

I expected a corrupted file and hoped anything I'd find would play anyway, but **there's nothing in the drive at all**--so I don't even have a starting point for file repair.  I don't even know if I should be looking for a .wav, .mp3, or something else.  I wonder if this can be recovered with a sector editor or similar.  I've done a few searches but can't find anything useful.  I've found a lot of recording tutorials and "failed drive, recover my computer" questions.

I'd obviously really like to obtain this audio--as would lots of family.  Does anyone know where I can begin?  The mixer may have been a Yamaha.  I can confirm brand/model if there's a chance that info will help.

I have Linux and Win7 at my disposal.  Free repair tools are better/preferred--as is Linux.  But of course whatever works.

Comment: Have you tried any deleted file recovery tools? There are quite a few that are free or almost free to use. That’s really your best chance if anything exists. If the drive wasn’t completely empty, you’re going to have a significantly harder time recovering a file of this size be because the file may have been fragmented and the pieces will be jumbled around.

Comment: I emptied the drive prior to the service, which hopefully mitigated fragmentation.  I've not yet tried file recovery.  I typically either back up important things or take the loss when it's gone.  Any specific tools you recommend?